# Problems installing Echo Nest Remix API on Mac?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to Python, and am trying to install the Echo Nest Remix API using the OS X 10.6 installer at http://code.google.com/p/echo-nest-remix/

I am using Python 2.7.2 but when I try to import pyechonest, I get an ImportError:

> no module named pyechonest

Would anyone be able to provide a walk-through of how to successfully install the Echo Nest Remix API using the OS X installer on the echo next remix site? I have been able to install numpy successfully, not sure why I am receiving errors after installing the echo nest remix API.

Answer (score 1):

The Remix installer for Mac works with Python 2.5 and Python 2.6. If you need to use it with Python 2.7, you might try installing Remix from source rather than from the installer package - that appears to have worked for a commenter on the google code page. Personally I'm not using anything specific to Python 2.7 so I'm just running my Remix stuff on 2.6.